# Scala Doobie does not return anything when using OR WHERE

Tags: scala, doobie

I am trying to select from database with several filters. Code:

```
// name is List("Denis", "Semen")
val query = name.map(_ + "%").mkString(" OR name LIKE ")  
sql"SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE name LIKE ${query+"%"}"
   .query[Contact]
   .to[List]
   .transact(tr)
```

Result query is like this: `SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE name LIKE Denis% OR name LIKE Semen%`

And i do not getting anything. I only get something when SELECT is with only one name: `SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE name LIKE Denis%`.

I've also tried this:

```
val query = name.map("'" + _ + "%'").mkString(" OR name LIKE ")  // 'denis%' OR NAME LIKE 'benis%'
```

Result query it like this: `SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE name LIKE 'Jhon%' OR name LIKE 'Lena%'`, but in Doobie there is no need to use `'`, so even one name will not return anything: `SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE name LIKE 'Jhon%'`.

Comment: I use `{ for { n<-names } yield {sql...} }.flatSequence` as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpolated value (`query`) is used as paramater *value* in your select. So when you have multiple names your actual SELECT would look like `SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE name LIKE 'Jhon% OR name LIKE Lena%'` (notice where the single quotes are - they include the phrase 'OR LIKE').

Use `++` on `Fragment` values to build up arbitrary SQL statements. Something like:

```
val query = name.map(name => fr"name LIKE ${name + "%"}").reduceOption((left, right) => left ++ fr" OR " ++ right).getOrElse(fr"1 = 0")
(sql"SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE " ++ query)
   .query[Contact]
   .to[List]
   .transact(tr)
```